# Values of exitflag in fminunc Matlab function is not consistant in Matlab 7.6 and 7.8

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I need to know what exitflags mean in function fminunc, in Matlab version 7.6.
Specifically, I get value -2 which is not listed in 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fminunc.html.
Thanks,
Farzane

Answer (score 1):

That documentation is the latest one. Why don't you try looking inside the help that comes with your MATLAB version? That might contain info.

If not, enter `type fminunc.m` at the command line to see the source code and look there to see what `-2` means.

Comment: I can only submit jobs to the system. Do not access to help, or command window.

Comment: Older documentation on the website is only accessible if you have a password. I don't have one, so can't help you there. Maybe you can submit a small job that reads the contents of `fminunc.m` and writes that to a file... you can then read the file and see :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** [This posting of the code](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~gerhard/classes/331/lab/fminunc.html) of the function seems to indicate that any negative value indicates `"FMINUNC did not converge to a solution"`

Comment: is `fmincon` the same as `fminunc`?

Comment: @d00b No, one is constrained and the other is unconstrained.  I guess Google deemed them similar enough.  I'll keep looking.